# What is the chronological order of appearance of Jyotirlingas?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, shiva-lingam, jyotirlinga

12 Jyotirlingas are shown in the pic. I'm interested to sort these Jyotirlingas based on the time of their appearance. ( To analyze the pattern they form once joined based on chronological order of their appearance) 
 
Can anyone give me chronological order of their appearances?  [image]

Comment: I think Kashi Vishwanatha Lingam would come in the first in the chronological order...

Answer (score 3):

While I have not been able to find any Pauranic reference as answer to this question, we chant the **"Dwadasha Jyotirlinga Stotram"** which is sung in praise of the twelve Jyotirlingas.  It would be logical and believable to accept this as the chronological order. The prayer swings from Western India to Southern India to Central India to the Himalayas to the Eastern Part before swinging back to the West and so on.  Therefore based on the "Dwadasha Jyotirlinga Stotram" the following is the chronological order:

(1) Somnath in Saurashtra, Gujarat

(2) Srisailam in Andhra Pradesh

(3) Mahakala in Ujjain in Madhya Pradesh

(4) Omkarnath in Madhya Pradesh

(5) Sri Vaidyanath in Bihar

(6) Sri Naganatha in Bet Dwarka, Gujarat

(7) Kedaranath in Himalayas

(8)Triyambikeshwar in Nashik, Maharashtra

(9)Ramalinga Swamy in Rameshwaram, Tamil Nadu

(10) Bhimashankar in Maharashtra

(11) Kashi Vishwanath at Varanasi, Uttar Pradesh

(12) Grishneshwar near Aurangabad, Maharashtra

As the stotra says :

> **ज्योतिर्मयद्दवाशलिङ्गकानां शिवात्मनां प्रोक्तमिदं क्रमेण|**
>
> **स्तोत्रं पठित्वा मनुजोsतिभक्त्या फलं तदा लोक्य निजं भजेच्च ||**

This is the list of the Twelve Jyotirlingas of shiva as they appeared, the individual who with devotion reads / chants this stotram will be blessed with beneficial fruits and attain the loka due after his death.

Comment: Dwadasa Jyotirlinga stotram is from the Shiva Purana.. See this page: http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/shivapuranam22.html